# Remove HTML element while keeping its content

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I have this HTML:

```
<p><img alt="" height="400" src="img.jpg" width="800" /></p>
```

And am trying to use PHP DomDocument to transform it to this:

```
<figure><img src="img.jpg"></figure>
```

This is my code:

```
$data='<p><img alt="" height="400" src="img.jpg" width="800" /></p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgtags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgtags as $key => $imgvalues){
    $parent = $imgvalues->parentNode;
    $imgsrc = $imgvalues->getAttribute('src');
    $newimg = $doc->createElement('img');
    $newimg->setAttribute('src', $imgsrc);
    $figure = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figure->appendChild($newimg);
    $imgvalues->parentNode->replaceChild($figure, $imgvalues);
}
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);
```

But the output is this:

```
<p><figure><img src="img.jpg"></figure></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove it before passing your `$data` to the loop using a `preg_replace` or you can do the same after your loop, whichever you like better:

```
$data = '<p><img alt="" height="400" src="img.jpg" width="800" /></p>';
$data = preg_replace('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/s', '$1', $data);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$imgtags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($imgtags as $key => $imgvalues) {
    $parent = $imgvalues->parentNode;
    $imgsrc = $imgvalues->getAttribute('src');
    $newimg = $doc->createElement('img');
    $newimg->setAttribute('src', $imgsrc);
    $figure = $doc->createElement('figure');
    $figure->appendChild($newimg);
    $imgvalues->parentNode->replaceChild($figure, $imgvalues);
}
$body1 = $doc->saveHTML($doc->documentElement);

var_dump($body1);
```

#### Output

```
 string(36) "<figure><img src="img.jpg"></figure>"
```

Comment: hi yes i thought to use preg_replace, but sometimes <p> has class or style attributes, and the preg_replace has to change, so thats why i'd like to use php dom

Comment: You should be using DOM to alter the original HTML as well.

Comment: Also note you've lost the attributes of the image; cloning the node will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You call `$imgvalues->parentNode->replaceChild()` which says to replace the child of the parent; so you're just replacing the child and not touching the parent.

What you want to do instead is deal with the parent of the parent. "But there isn't one in my HTML," you say. However, there's always an implied root element when you're dealing with HTML, so this works:

```
<?php
$html = '<p><img alt="" height="400" src="img.jpg" width="800" /></p>';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach ($images as $img) {
    $img_copy = $img->cloneNode(true);
    $p = $img->parentNode;
    $fig = $dom->createElement("figure");
    $fig->appendChild($img_copy);
    $p->parentNode->replaceChild($fig, $p);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<figure><img alt="" height="400" src="img.jpg" width="800"></figure>
```